# Webview Landscape

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I'm trying to figure out a way to make it so that my ios webview is in landscape mode while the rest of my app is in portrait. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have a video section that I link out to vimeo. The vimeo video player is brought up in webview which is the portion I would like in landscape.

Answer (score 4):

you must do it programatically in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
`webview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);`

Comment: In my app delegate? Like the following?  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
}

Comment: yes you test if you are in landscape mode and you rotate your webview

Comment: pardon my ignorance, I'm a newbie to this all. Is this how you're saying to do it:   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
    webview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
}

Comment: Hey Touti - I really need to figure this one out. Any chance you can help me out. I tried the following: (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientatio‌​n { return YES; webview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2); } ... it gives me the following errors: "expected body method" and "Expected selector for object c method". Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I tried this in my MainViewController.m and got the error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'webview'" ... thoughts on why that is?

Comment: you had this error because webviewis not decalred in the MainViewController...declare it or use this code in other view controller

Comment: What other view controller are you talking about? Do you mean my app delegate? I tried "- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    webview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
}" in my app delegate but got the same error.