# Phonegap/cordova IOS Landscape Video

Tags: jquery, ios5, cordova

**The Problem:**

I have created my application with portrait orientation enabled, but I need to support landscape orientation when I launch a video in full screen.

**Things I've tried:**

- [Webview Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982518/webview-landscape)
- [Phonegap - Prevent Rotation While Still Having Auto-Orientation Enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444031/phonegap-prevent-rotation-while-still-having-auto-orientation-enabled)
- https://github.com/acti0nm4n/Phonegap-Orientation-iOS

**Requirements:**

- Works with Cordova 1.8
- Works with IOS 5.1
- Jquery Friendly
- Will pass apple inspection
- Preferably a fix that works for both android and ios, though IOS is the priority

There are many people out there looking for the same solution. Please be specific and thorough in your answers so that we can test the solution accurately. I've seen this done time and time again in apps, but for some reason I haven't found an answer.

I have looked high and low for a solution to this problem but each time come up short. It seems  like such a simple problem that should have an easy fix. I know there are several posts out there on how to do this but I haven't had ny luck with the answers on those posts. Please let me know if you have a solution that would work for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems to be the most promising but the originator may need some help making it work with cordova 1.8 ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193860/iphone-orientation-phonegap#comment15090169_11193860

Answer (score 0):

We use video.js in our phonegap/cordova app, and have never had an issue.  We chose to use video.js in our mobile client because we use it throughout our service.

Additional context:
* We're playing off the network, not local storage.
* We deliver webm, mp4 and ogg files (I'm not sure which is being used on iOS, but we generate all three for various purposes.)